# Airflow Sechulder error ERROR - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=1234) last sent a heartbeat 50.72 seconds ago! Restarting it

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have recently installed airflow 2.1.3 using apache-airflow helm repo on Azure AKS cluster. But post the installation, The Dag files are not getting displayed on the UI. The reason could be the scheduler getting terminated consistently. Below is the error. Can anyone please help me with the below issue?

```html
[2021-10-28 05:16:49,322] {manager.py:254} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 1268
[2021-10-28 05:16:49,339] {settings.py:51} INFO - Configured default timezone Timezone('UTC')
[2021-10-28 05:17:39,997] {manager.py:414} ERROR - DagFileProcessorManager (PID=1268) last sent a heartbeat 50.68 seconds ago! Restarting it
[2021-10-28 05:17:39,998] {process_utils.py:100} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 1268
[2021-10-28 05:17:40,251] {process_utils.py:66} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=1268, status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='05:16:48') (1268) terminated with exit code 0
[2021-10-28 05:17:40,256] {manager.py:254} INFO - Launched DagFileProcessorManager with pid: 1313
[2021-10-28 05:17:40,274] {settings.py:51} INFO - Configured default timezone Timezone('UTC')
```

Comment: Hi @Sumith08 were you able to figure this issue out?

Answer (score 1):

I have previously been able to fix this by setting a higher value in **airflow.cfg** for `scheduler_health_check_threshold`

For Ex:
`scheduler_health_check_threshold = 240`

Also, ensure that `orphaned_tasks_check_interval` is greater than the value that you set for `scheduler_health_check_threshold`

Comment: Hi Vinay, thanks for your reply. But even after setting the value, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Increase

```
dag_file_processor_timeout
```

in airflow.cfg or set AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_FILE_PROCESSOR_TIMEOUT as higher than 50 will be helpful. (default: 50, seconds)

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-file-processor-timeout

Your messages just mean a timeout of that values.